# DocuSign Account Branding

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to create different branding for different users in my DocuSign account.

I have number of users into my DocuSign account associated with different groups.
They are grouped in certain ways and each group needs to see different logo/branding/landing page for their DocuSign envelopes. How can I accomplish that?

I know that you can create different branding for users but I was not able to associate branding to a specific user/group. Could it be possible that my DocuSign account does not have that feature?

Thanks,

Minal

Answer (score 1):

On an enterprise account I can:

1. Go to Preferences -> Groups
2. Select a Group from the dropdown
3. Select the "Brands" button

That brings up a list of "Available Brands" on the left and "Group Brands" on the right.